# Are there any downsides to storing properties on Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript

I know that Javascript Arrays are actually objects, and because they are objects, they can have properties. Here's an example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.currentIndex = 2;
a.next = function() { ... };
a.prev = function() { ... };

a.length // returns 3
```

To me this seems like it could come in very handy. I see numerous reasons why you might want to store state or utility functions on the actual array itself and not on some other variable. It even seems better than having the array as a property of an object with the other stuff stored on that object.

**Here's my question:**

Does anyone know of any issues with storing properties on a Javascript array? Does it work in all browsers? Is there any evidence that this will change with future versions of Javascript? Is there any general wisdom about whether or not it's a good practice?

(p.s. For the record, I don't need to iterate over the array with a for...in loop. I understand that such a loop would include the properties as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing out one more thing -- None of the "copying" array prototype functions will copy any of your extra properties, if that's important, i.e. `.splice`, `.slice`, `concat` will give you new "clean" arrays without `currentIndex`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Since you already ruled out the `for in` issue, my answer here is a clear "no" - there is no issue to worry about. All `Array.prototype` methods will only apply on the "indexed" keys (0...n).

The best example here is the well know jQuery library, it also uses Array-Like objects to store DOM nodes on but it also has lots of methods which are attached to that object (jQuery uses the prototype there tho). However, other librarys like Zepto, just put those methods directly on the "array" object itself.

So again, no there is no other caveat and you're save doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works in all browsers. And it is valid javascript (arrays are objects). One could think of a number of reasons why you want to use the Array constructor instead of an object, but if this is your preferred coding style, go with it.